# VS Code won't let me stage changes (new folders created)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Hopefully, this is not something difficult to fix.

I am working on my project and when I try to stage my changes, which are some new folders and React components, if I press on the stage changes button nothing happens.

[image]

Should you need any more details please just ask for it, as I am a bit lost at the moment.

P.S. I have already tried to cancel my git repository and re-initiate it but does not fix the problem.

Here is the output of `git status`:

[image]

And if I run `git add .` nothing changes.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Does it happen on other machines with this repository as well? If you can reproduce this issue on a different machine, what are the steps to do so? If you can't reproduce it on another machine, does re-installing Visual Studio Code help?

Comment: Also try running `git status` in a terminal, and `git add <somefile>` with the terminal. Does that work? Or are there any helpful error messages that might indicate why Visual Studio Code is failing to do it itself?

Comment: @Omer Thanks for your reply. I will post the output for git status, so should be easier to start from there

Comment: That seems to be a submodule. Not sure that VSCode supports submodules in this fashion. Try opening that subfolder in a seperate window and see what it says. It should allow you to stage and commit the changes made there. After you've commited them you should be able to stage the submodule pointer in the parent repo.